Event not received in Pusher console
My event is not sent to Pusher. The broadcastOn method is called, but I don't see the event in the pusher debug console.
This is not a credential issue, when I use https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php?tab=readme-ov-file with my credentials. It works.
Laravel version : 11.25.0
Here is my event :
class PlaceAddedEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $idSearch;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct($idSearch)
    {
        $this->idSearch = $idSearch;

        Log::info(__CLASS__ . ":" . __FUNCTION__ . " id = " . $idSearch);
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {

        Log::info('PlaceAddedEvent broadcasted on channel: channel-place');

        return [
            new Channel('channel-place'),
        ];
    }
}

(BTW when I use ShouldBroadcast instead of ShouldBroadcastNow, the broadcastOn method is not called)
The event is triggered in a artisan command with :
event(new PlaceAddedEvent($idSearch));

Please note that the broadcastOn() method is triggered, I see it on the log :
[2024-09-27 05:40:37] local.INFO: Broadcasting [App\Events\PlaceAddedEvent] on channels [channel-place] with payload:
{
    "idSearch": "1",
    "socket": null
}  

In the broadcasting file I have : (and of courses env variables are correctly defined in the .env file)
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'ap3',
                'host' => 'api-ap3.pusher.com',
                'port' => 80,
                'scheme' => 'http',
                'encrypted' => false,
                'useTLS' => false,
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],

If I use https, it it the same.
Just before I emit the event, I do :
$pusherConfig = config('broadcasting.connections.pusher');

$broadcastDriver = config('broadcasting.default');

$this->info('Broadcast Driver: ' . $broadcastDriver);
$this->info('Pusher Config:');
$this->info(print_r($pusherConfig, true));

To make sures all variables are well set.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Are you sure your queue is setup correctly and running? What queue connection are you using?

QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

If you're triggering with artisan, can you make sure that all your config variables are loaded correctly? Try to echo the env('PUSHER_APP_KEY') or any other value just to see if it displays the correct value

That is what I did. I wrote it in my question (the end)
